# Mobile application development in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone

I want to write my first application for mobile phones,and I just opened Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and I'm wondering where should I start. I noticed that there is no New Project->Smart devices like it was in VS2012. What kind of project should I use? I think about the asp.net mvc 4 but what I want to make it's not really a web-based application,I want something local,with local database.

Comment: Install the windows phone sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [Windows Phone SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35471) and then you should have it under

```
Templates -> Visual C# -> Windows Phone
```

Comment: I tried but I have win7 and it's not compatible with sdk 8. Does the SDK 7 work?

Comment: Tried installing the SDK 7 - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27570

Comment: I just realized I already had it. Can I include PCL in this version?